# How can I use an arraylist to store coordinates to draw random points of different colors in a fixed area?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

The assignment is to draw chips on a supposed cookie at random points while counting each chip and storing the coordinates so that each chip doesn't move. Each chip should be a different color and initiated on a mouse press.

I've tried to put the coordinates into an array, multiple arrays a single array list and tried to use if and for loops. The results before were that it would generate a single chip of a different colour each click (sort of because sometimes the random number generated is outside of my specified range). After using and looping through multiple array lists the current behaviour is that it generates a grid and the count is exponentially growing with each click, some points have a lot of overlap and the chips in the grid all ave one colour i.e. The last to be assigned

//Put graphics code here
    public void draw(Graphics g){

ArrayList coordinates = new ArrayList();

```
  col1= generator.nextInt(256) + 0;
  col2= generator.nextInt(256) + 0;
  col3= generator.nextInt(256) + 0;

  canvasMaxWidth=800;
  canvasMaxHeight=600;
  canvasMinWidth=400;
  canvasMinHeight=200;

   int newX = (int) (Math.random() * canvasMaxWidth) + canvasMinWidth;
  int newY = (int) (Math.random() * canvasMaxHeight) + canvasMinHeight;
     Point point = new Point(newX, newY);


 g.setColor(new Color(205,133,63));
 g.fillOval(canvasMinWidth,canvasMinHeight,400,400); 



 for(Point point : coordinates){
if(point.y > 249 && point.y < 549 && point.x > 449 && point.x < 749){
    g.setColor(new Color(col1, col2, col3));
    g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, 7, 7);
   }
  }             

g.setColor(Color.black); 
g.drawString("Number of Sprinkles: "+ count, 100, 80);  


  }

   //Code to respond to a mouse press
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouse){




     }
```

The expected result is essentially a speckled disk that counts each speckle on the disk with each speckle not moving.

At present it appears that no point is moving but there's not a lot of randomness to what is happening. the speckles multiply each click vs iterate and form a grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Point> coordinates = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

is much easier to track coordinates rather than using two separate lists. Everything is happening in a grid format because you are using a nested for loop for i and j.

You are currently performing:
if i = 0, 1, 2 and j = 0 , 1, 2

```
i  j
0  0
0  1
0  2
1  0
1  1
1  2
2  0
2  1
2  2
```

so you can see where the grid-like layout is coming from. Using a Point object, you could instead do:

```
for(Point point : coordinates){
    if(point.y > 249 && point.y < 549 && point.x > 449 && point.x < 749){
        g.setColor(new Color(col1, col2, col3);
        g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, 7, 7);
    }
}
```

I'm unsure why you are using a counter, as it would be performing for the length of the coordinates. If you would like to add randomness, then you can dynamically create values using the Random class.

```
int colorValue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
```

and if you wanted to perform random positions, you could randomly generate them through:

```
int newX = (int) (Math.random() * (canvasMaxWidth - canvasMinWidth)) + canvasMinWidth;
int newY = (int) (Math.random() * (canvasMaxHeight - canvasMinHeight)) + canvasMinHeight;
Point point = new Point(newX, newY);
```

Edit with your code:

```
int newX = (int) (Math.random() * (canvasMaxWidth - canvasMinWidth)) + canvasMinWidth;
int newY = (int) (Math.random() * (canvasMaxHeight - canvasMinHeight)) + canvasMinHeight;
Point point = new Point(newX, newY);
coordinates.add(point);
counter++;

redList.add((int) (Math.random() * 255));
greenList.add((int) (Math.random() * 255));
blueList.add((int) (Math.random() * 255));

 g.setColor(new Color(205,133,63));
 g.fillOval(canvasMinWidth,canvasMinHeight,400,400); 



 for(int z = 0; z < coordinates.size(); z++){
    if(coordinates.get(z).y > 249 && coordinates.get(z).y < 549 && coordinates.get(z).x > 449 && coordinates.get(z).x < 749){
        g.setColor(new Color(redList.get(z).intValue(), greenList.get(z).intValue(), blueList.get(z).intValue()));
        g.fillOval(coordinates.get(z).x, coordinates.get(z).y, 7, 7);
    }
 }
```

Edit #2: here is a sample of how you would have the static variables

```
public class myClass{
    static ArrayList<Point> coordinates = new ArrayList<Point>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> redList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> greenList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> blueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static int counter = 0;
```

Comment: Wow these are a lot of helpful suggestions and I was using the count to count each point that was generated but I'll try your suggestions. Hopefully it works out for me.

Comment: Having an issue based on your suggestions. It's prompting me that "point is already defined" when the second use of the variable is selected for the loop. What should I do?

Comment: You're probably just attempting to define it again by accident. Mind updating your question post with the code so I can see it?

Comment: Updated. Additionally I've been moving the variable definitions for canvas max and min around to see if it changes anything

Comment: Issue is you have: Point point = new Point(newX, newY); and then: for(Point point : coordinates), where both  instances are named point.

Comment: Yeah I get that part so I'm wondering if renaming the variable storing the x and y coordinates would create a problem for the looping function or is it that the variable declaration is intended to be used to store each point after the loop and hence should follow the fillOval statement in the if loop? I changed it to Point points =new Point(newX newY) and it's not drawing anything even though it does comple.

Comment: The for loop is simply taking the current points that you have stored within the coordinates list and drawing them. If you are looking to create a new point whenever this method is called, then add the new point to the coordinates list before going into the loop (hence having the for loop draw it). The actual names used don't matter much, as long as you now what they mean. You could rename it for(Point currentPoint : coordinates){ if you felt like it and then set point.x and point.y to currentPoint.x and currentPoint.y

Comment: Ok so if I'm understanding correctly I can use coordinates.add(newX,newY); before the loop and that should take care of the problem (assuming I change the loop variables to reflect the suggested currentPoint name or whatever i pick)?

Comment: I edited with your code to clarify a bit more. You would use coordinates.add(point) since coordinates is a list containing 'Point' objects. Now that the point is added to coordinates before the for loop, when the for loop runs, it will iterate over the newly added point (along with the previously stored points that are already in coordinates).

Comment: I'd like to point out that you are creating the coordinates list within your draw method (as per the code in your original post), and so when the method is done running (once it is done drawing), it will 'delete' the coordinates list. You should make it a static (class) variable to make sure it stays stored.

Comment: Ok so updating. That helps. It draws a single point but it's back to square one because the points leave the canvas after a new one is generated so the problem now is to store these points. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: Aha...so in my variable declaration in the draw method I should set it to static correct? It being the coordinates list

Comment: Correct: make it a static variable underneath where you write "public class [your class name]{" . It would be "static ArrayList<Point> coordinates = new ArrayList<Point>();"

Comment: It's saying illegal start of expression now. Should I make it a public variable and put it outside the method?

Comment: Updated to clarify. See if that helps.

Comment: Ok that worked I put it as part of the Sprinkles method which is the main method that gets run and now I have random sprinkles everywhere. EXCELLENT but they're still all the same color so I'm guessing I should take that part out of the loop. Last thing is to count each sprinkle. Thanks so much for your help so far. I hope you won't feel too bothered if I ask for anymore assistance with this.

Comment: To create a new color for each point and then re-draw each point with the same colors they were created with, you would have to store the integer values of the colors in the same way you are storing the coordinates list (in a static way). I've updated my post to reflect these changes in the code. You also would make counter static and then iterate it by one each time the method is called to count the number of points (I added that too).

Comment: Ok I updated with your suggestions and the only error I'm getting is in relation to intValue. Is there something I need to import for that particular keyword? I imported java.lang and it still has the same issue

Comment: No I miswrote it; it is a method. Change it to intValue()

Comment: Ok so it looks like in your code you just left off the opening and closing brackets to call the method "()". It works to generate each sprinkle with a different color but not on each mouse press. I think that's probably a problem with the math method because when I was using random it was generating values outside the range. The counter does count but it's basically counting each mouse click which is out of sync with each sprinkle. I'm not sure what to do about that.

Comment: I wrote the code with the assumption that for each time you called the draw method, you wanted one new random sprinkle to be made. That is why I have it counting the mouse clicks, but maybe my understanding of what you wanted was wrong.  As for the clicks not making a sprinkle, that may be due to the math not being correct (making a sprinkle outside of the canvas).

Comment: I think I might see the issue with the sprinkles not appearing: I had two formulas posted and I didn't update your code segment with the correct formula by accident. You can try it now to see if it works better. (The updated code is the int newX = ... and int newY = ....)

Comment: oooh It needed to be the MaxWidth-MinWidth etc. I see and yes now what happens is that the program runs with 1 sprinkle present and almost every click generates a sprinkle (or the sprinkles I can't see might be the same color as the cookie) I think this works as the solution.